# how to add spectrum while playing audio files in windows 8 xaml C# apps

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

i have created a player using media element in windows 8 xaml apps.i want to add spectrum to my mediaelment when playing audio files.how to add spectrum to mediaelement using xaml C# in windows 8?

how to diagnose audio in adding spectrum to media element in windows 8 xaml apps using C#

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about an audio visualizer?  Try these examples [here](http://salusemediakit.codeplex.com/) and [here](http://wpfsvl.codeplex.com/).